# Automatically create a Pull Request in a parent repo for a submodule project using GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a parent project for all our modules which are contained in submodules. We want to be able to create a PR in the parent repo when a submodule repo is updated, and update the branch checkouts.

Is is possible to create a PR in a parent repo, from a GitHub Actions workflow that has just published in a child submodule repo? I'm guessing this may be be possible through the GitHub API, but I couldn't see any marketplace actions that fit the need.

Comment: SO after a little more searching, this may be a possible answer, but requires an automated bot to monitor the parent repo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853756/are-there-any-github-actions-that-can-create-pull-requests-for-submodule-updates
Not ideal, but is one solution if there are no other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the following GitHub Action:

```yaml
name: Submodule updates to a parent repo

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main

jobs:
  update:
    name: Update submodules
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with: 
          repository: org/parent_repo
          token: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_TOKEN_GITHUB }}

      - name: Update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote

      - name: Commit the changes
        run: |
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions - update submodules"
          git add --all
          git commit -m "Update submodules" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push
```

Changes required in the above workflow:

- Change `org/parent_repo` to the username and the repository name where you wish to make the changes.
- Generate a Personal Access Token (PAT) and save it as a `PRIVATE_TOKEN_GITHUB` over GitHub Secrets to use it fluently.

Comment: I like this approach but it only works if the parent repo does not have any branch protections.  But it's a start, thanks